# API receiving unknown body or parameter in Typescript, how to check the type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

I am working on a Rest API in TypeScript.

The part I'm working on receives as a parameter a Type object containing a body attribute as being of type "Unknown".

I have to check that the body attribute that I received in my object as a parameter is strictly compliant with my Type / Interface, here in the exemple : "account"

And that's what I can't seem to do ...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When a variable/parameter is unknown you have to check for the contents of the object in order to use it like you want to.

Couple of ways to do that, one is to do it in line, checking each field as you need it (check if it is an object, check that "property in variable" , check the type of the property, and so on. It's messy, and still doesn't verify that the object is the type you want, just makes it safe to access things in it.

The other, cleaner way is to write a type guard function. A type guard function is a function whose responsibility is to verify that the object is compliant with a desired type. It looks something like this:

```
function isAccount(val: unknown): val is Account 
{ 
    let result = false;
    ... Check the shape of the object ... 
    return result; 
}
```

How much you check the object in the method is up to you. Typescript will assume if you call that method in an if/control block that the object is that type (even if it isn't). If it isn't then you will blow up at runtime. So it is best to check for the existence of any properties that are non optional, and to check the types of any matching properties are allowed (no dates in string fields, etc) extra properties are not an issue, because as long as you can use it as an account that is all that needs to matter.

So then to use you just

```
if (isAccount(param)) { ... param is now tested as an Account!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `type predicate`:

```
function isAccount(input: any): input is Account {
  return (
    typeof input === 'object' &&
    input !== null &&
    typeof input.username === 'string' &&
    typeof input.password === 'string'
  );
}
```